# how can we add frequency to, arima.sim. to avoid error while decomposing

Tags: r, time-series

I am getting error while decomposing a Time series i created. Becuase it doesn't have frequency/periods i guess.

I created:-

> ts.sim=arima.sim(n=100, list(ar=0.9), innov=rnorm(100))

When decompose:-

> decompose(ts.sim)

Error in decompose(ts.sim) : time series has no or less than 2 periods.

So, I thought of adding frequency to it, as in (TS <- ts(1:8, frequency = 4)
But this frequency option is not there in "arima.sim"

> ts.sim = arima.sim(n=100, list(ar=0.9), innov=rnorm(100), frequency=10)

Error in rand.gen(n.start, ...) : unused argument (frequency = 10)

kind regards,